# Do local and remote machines have to run the same version of ROS?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04, and with it ROS Melodic Morenia on my workstation.  I have a Raspberry Pi based bobot running Lubuntu 16.04 with ROS Kinetic Kame.  Will these machines be able to communicate, or will I have to try and upgrade the Pi to 18.04 with Melodic too ?

I have already tried to make this work.  The workstation sees topics being published on the Pi. However I see a raspicam_node on the Pi publishing at 10 hz on the Pi.  When I check the rate of raspicam_node, on the workstation, rostopic says that no messages have been published. I need to determine if this is because the versions of ROS are incompatible, or if I am doing something else wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305764/do-local-and-remote-machines-have-to-run-the-same-version-of-ros-?/) by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2018-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As long as the specific messages have not been changed between the two ROS distributions it should be work fine maybe your ip address didn't set correctly

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-10-15**:
Yes , from my experience , it works fairly well across different variants .

**Comment by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) on 2018-10-15**:
I remember having huge problems with some marker messages when I was using a combo ROS Kinetic + ROS Indigo. I would highly recommend sticking to the same distro if possible

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS too and below are some of my experiences

1. Both workstation and the mobile robot can have different rosdistro. My current setup is Lunar + Kinect
2. Never forget to export the following three things in your terminal or ~/.bashrc. All the addresses below are for display purpose. It is different for everyone. In my case, without any one of them, the whole thing will not work.

- #export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.118:11311/ (address displayed on workstation's roscore)
- #export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.118 (address of master/slave)
- #export ROS_IP=192.168.1.118 (address of master/slave)

3. Lastly, try synchronize time of both workstation and the mobile robot. For example, try  `sudo ntpdate 192.168.6.104   (Address of master)` on your mobile robot either by ssh or ~/.bashrc

---

Originally posted by [KinWah](https://answers.ros.org/users/38047/kinwah/) with karma: 91 on 2018-10-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1